# How can a post have a score of 3 with only 2 views

Tags: bug, status-declined, questions

Look at the top post. Score of 3, but 2 views. You can upvote without viewing it. How did this happen?

[image]

Comment: I've seen this happening as well. It might be to do with [caching](//shouldiblamecaching.com).

Comment: How would caching affect it? And how to make links in comments? @TheThonnu

Comment: You use `[link text](link URL)`, just like in posts. And caching was just a guess.

Comment: Google eventual consistency

Comment: @mousetail holy high availability

Comment: new update just dropped (what r/AnarchyChess is leaking here too?)

Comment: Why all the close votes?

Comment: Because this isn't specific to this site

Comment: This has probably been asked on meta meta many times before

Comment: Adding the decline tag since this is a well-known bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you search [`view count caching`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=view+count+caching) in the MSE search box, you'll find [View count and vote count are not matching on a question [duplicate]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279780/997587), which points to [Does Stack Exchange use caching and if so, how?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69164/997587). Quoting:

> Conceptually, each site has 3 distinct caches:
>
> 1. A "local cache," which can only be accessed from 1 server/site pair
>
>    - Contains things like user sessions, and pending view count updates

Answer (score -4):

View counts are unreliable.  Don't trust them.

Comment: Not helpful @Mark